# iOS 6.1 Table View Screen Footer

Tags: iphone, ios, screen, footer

My iPhone app starts off (using a storyboard) with a navigation controller, then a table view controller; what I want to do next is use a tool bar to provide options to go to other table view controllers.  The problem is that the tool bar is buried off screen.  I would like it to be more like a screen footer, always visible to the user.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The toolbar was originally added to the tableview so as the list got longer the toolbar showed up at the end of the list hidden off the screen unless you scrolled down.

To fix this problem in the Attributes section of the Navigation Controller in the Simulated Metrics I set Bottom Bar to Toolbar. I then did the same thing in the Table View Controller. I then added the Bar Button Items to the toolbar on the Table View Controller.

Then I had to control where the toolbar appeared downstream by calling

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
}
```

in the applicable table view controllers and setting YES or NO.

For some reason I was unable to find good documentation for this process. It probably is out there, but I have included it here for others who may have this problem.